# iphone view overlay

Tags: iphone, uiview, uinavigationbar

I have a client who recently requested this:
 [image: overlay]

My thoughts were that the text could be better displayed on the back of a flipover view and that it looks like it could be an issue in the approval process. Is There any way to even do this, do I even want to try?  Are there resources you can share? 
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: I should clarify that the NavigationBar and the Table would slide over when taping the picture behind. One tap would make it show and the other tap would make the bar and the table hide.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually pretty good. It's often hard to get clients to give you requirements, and this at least shows you what they're trying to achieve. I'd spend some time reworking the UI so that it will be acceptable in the app store (assuming you're going to publish there) and perhaps more in keeping with the normal use of iOS UI elements. Prepare to give your client a bit of an explanation about why this particular design leaves something to be desired, but try to come up with a design that they'll agree is obviously better. (There's plenty of room for improvement here, so it shouldn't be too hard.)

If your client is absolutely wedded to this exact UI, it might be time to find a new client. But if they're reasonable, thoughtful, and a little bit flexible, this might be the beginning of a nice app.

Comment: I added some details to what the picture actually means, the problem is the client is not flexible about the changes.

Comment: You can always show them Apple's App Store Review Guidelines. There's at least one item in there that says using standard UI elements in nonstandard ways may lead to rejection. I've never seen a partial nav bar like you're showing in an iPhone app, and I doubt it'd be accepted. You could hide the nav bar when not needed, though.

Comment: I know! thats what I did, I sent links and reasons why i thought it would violate the guidelines, I figure I check with other developers. I've seen crazy stuff done with in ios but this seemed not only ugly but also not very functional

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.  Put the picture (UIImageView) inside a wrapper UIView.  Put the text in a UITextView also in the wrapper UIView.  Then animate a flip transition between them that brings whichever one you want to the bottom of the subview stack.
You can check for potential UI violations in Apple's HIG: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: I am not sure I get what you are trying to say. I know how to do a flip transition that's what I Want the client to agree to, but instead he wants to have the piece of navigationBar and the UITableView on top of another view while still having the other part visible. I added some details to de description

Comment: I'm a little clearer on what you want.  I agree with Caleb about redesigning the UI.  But if you want the table to slide in/out, then set the table frame so .origin.x > main_view.frame.origin.x+main_view.frame.size.width (off to the right).  Then in your animation block, tableView.frame.origin.x -= tableView.frame.size.width  (move it to where you want it.)

Comment: I am trying to slide in the navigation bar along with the view from the right and on top of the current view. I'm assuming you mean .origin.x means the origin of the table, would I do the same for the navigation bar?

Comment: I assume the nav bar and the table are both subviews of some container view.  Just do the frame adjustment on that container view and it's contents will follow.

Answer (score 0):

```
+(id)showAlert{
    UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Overlay" bundle:nil];
    Overlay *alert = (Overlay*)controller.view;
    //alert.iTag = iiTag;
    alert.tag = iiTag;
    return alert;
}

-(void)addAnimation{
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.001, 0.001);
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3/1.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(bounce1AnimationStopped)];
     self.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.1, 1.1);

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)bounce1AnimationStopped {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3/2];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(bounce2AnimationStopped)];
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.9,0.9);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
- (void)bounce2AnimationStopped {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3/2];
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}

- (CGAffineTransform)transformForOrientation {
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        return CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI*1.5);
    } else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        return CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
    } else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        return CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI);
    } else {
        return CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    }
}

-(void)stopAnimatton{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:2.0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMake(00.1, 00.1,0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```